# Expression expected in TSX

Tags: typescript, tsx

```
 function conatinstemplatename(): boolean{
       let filtered = props.sessionLanguages.filter(x => x.templateName !== ' ').toArray();
       (filtered.length > 0)? return true : return false;
    }
```

The above line of code is returning expression expected error near the conditional statement.

Answer (score 2):

You cant `return` inside the ternary operator. Return the whole expression.

```
function conatinstemplatename(): boolean{
 let filtered = props.sessionLanguages.filter(x => x.templateName !== ' ').toArray();

 return (filtered.length > 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: or just:  `return filtered.length > 0`